Integrating Generative AI coding assistance in Emacs
Emacs currently supports AI-assisted coding through packages like Copilot and various chat interfaces. Copilot is good at completing code in place but not at making larger code changes. Chat interfaces are good at answering general questions, but less at understanding the entire code base and are tedious to use for coding. Some newer editors are incorporating more extensive generative AI features for end-to-end coding assistance (e.g., Cursor, Zed).
Are there any ongoing projects or packages in development that aim to expand Emacs' generative AI capabilities for coding that take a more holistic approach, with features like:

Ability to scan the entire project code base.
Chat interface to answer questions about project code base.
Generate and apply code changes based on human language instructions.
Optional: ability to configure and use different models.


Your query would be better on a discussion site, such as Reddit. This site is for specific Q&A, especially how-to.

I believe that I am asking how this type of environment might be created in emacs. I'm not interested in a discussion, but in a technical answer.

Too vague.  Ask a specific question about something you tried as a solution to your quest.

I specifically mentioned Copilot and gptel.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

I've tried to make the question more specific.

you are looking for an Emacs version of Cursor

Exactly right

That would be Emacsor
